# How check correct url protocol in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, open-uri

I have list of 50,000 websites and I want to know what kind of protocol they have. All the website i have has all the names.com or like something.com but none of them have 
http://google.com. I did try to run the each and check manually like..

```
require 'rubygems'

require 'open-uri'
require 'io/console'
require 'open_uri_redirections'
require 'openssl'

OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE



filename = "./testfile.txt"
destination = File.open("./11aa.txt", "a")

newArray = Array.new
newArray = IO.readlines(filename)
newArray.each do |url|
begin
    puts "#{url}"
    if open(url,:read_timeout=>2 )
        destination.write "#{url}"      
    end

rescue => e
  puts e.message
end
    end
```

which did work but takes forever to finish. I am looking for better algorithm to check.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "protocol"? The IP protocol used for the URL?

Comment: I mean scheme "http" or "https". I don't want to miss any websites so i need to check if that one is exist or not. And then i need to run anemone scrapper on it. so I have to decide  before hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Protocol"? As in the IP protocol used to connect to a host as defined by the URL?

```
require 'uri'

URI.parse('http://foo.com').scheme # => "http"
URI.parse('https://foo.com').scheme # => "https"
URI.parse('ftp://foo.com').scheme # => "ftp"
URI.parse('scp://foo.com').scheme # => "scp"
```

If you want to know whether a site accepts HTTPS vs. HTTP, I'd start by checking for HTTPS, as the majority of sites allow HTTP:

```
require 'net/http'

%w[
  example.com
  www.example.com
  mail.google.com
  account.dyn.com
].each do |url|
  begin
    Net::HTTP.start(url, 443, :use_ssl => true) {}
    puts "#{url} is HTTPS"
  rescue
    puts "#{url} is HTTP"
  end
end
# >> example.com is HTTP
# >> www.example.com is HTTP
# >> mail.google.com is HTTPS
# >> account.dyn.com is HTTPS
```

Even though mail.google.com and account.dyn.com are HTTPS, if you test them for HTTP first, you'll see they also have that protocol. Some sites will redirect their HTTP request to their HTTPS server, others run both to allow a user to decide whether they want HTTP or HTTPS. You can test both protocols to figure out which cases are true.

`start` doesn't require a block, but by providing an empty one it will automatically close the connection immediately after establishing it.

Sites don't necessarily run their web services on ports 80 and 443. As a result, assuming the connection should be to one of those ports isn't necessarily right and could give you bad results if they use a different one. 8080 and 8081 are also often used so those should be checked too.

Also, a site might respond on a port, but its content could be a redirect pointing you to the real port they want you to use, so you need to also consider whether you should only care about the connection succeeding, or look inside the HTTPd headers, or actually read the entire page returned, and parse it in case it's a software redirect.

In other words, a connection succeeding doesn't tell you enough about what the site wants you to use, you'll have to conduct additional tests too.

Answer (score 0):

Which protocol do you care about most? Is HTTPS preferable over HTTP? Some have both, some are redirects (http://www.google.com is a 302)

If you dont care which one it is, then go with http first as its probably more likely, so calls to it should be considerably faster.

Also, I'd drop the read_timeout down to 1 or even 500ms. If a site doesnt respond within that time, it might as well be dead (we're talking a simple response, not fully downloading all assets for the DOM).

Comment: That make sense I used ur idea little bit.

Answer (score 0):

> require 'open-uri'

```
def correct_url_protocol(single_url)
    puts "-----------------------In correct_url_protocol--------------------------"

        begin
         good_link = "http://www.#{single_url}"
            if open(good_link, read_timeout: 3,:allow_redirections => :all)
                "http://www.#{single_url}"
            else 
                "https://www.#{single_url}"
            end 
        rescue => e
            exp = e.message
            if exp.match("redirection forbidden")
                good_link = "https://www.#{single_url}"
                good_link

                end
            puts e.message
            good_link
        end 
end
```

I think this is the best approach I created. Let me know if any better.

Comment: You assume a site starts with `www.` which isn't a valid assumption. You also assume a site name doesn't already start with it, which again, isn't a safe assumption. A lot of sites redirect to their `www` equivalent automatically, but there are still sites out there that have no `www` prefix, such as Stack Overflow for instance. Also, you assume that a connection is `https` if you can't `open` a connection, but that's not valid unless you test to see if it actually exists.

Comment: Don't do `exp.match("redirection forbidden")`. Instead use `e.message["redirection forbidden"]` which is faster and accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: @theTinMan you are right about www to redirection if that the case then it should work when i am calling open(good_link, read_timeout: 3,:allow_redirections => :all). I think this allow_redirection => all is the key here. Again that was one of my major problem. its so weird that there is nothing like this out there. I was wondering to create gem for it when i have some little time. Thanks for your input again.

Comment: I'm not sure why you care what protocol they support. If you handle redirections it becomes a moot point; Look at the URL they redirect to and enable SSL if necessary. Or, just rely on OpenURI to handle things.